# How to git reset --hard HEAD^ root of repo without affecting submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

After making a temporary commit to the root of a repo, which has submodules, I haphazardly ran `git reset --hard HEAD^` with the intention of just deleting said commit on the master's root - but to my dismay affect all submodule repos too....

I just wanted to delete the head commit on the root repo.

Is there a better/safer way to accomplish this task without affecting the submodule repos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *default default* for `git reset` is `--no-recurse-submodules` (as is true for checkout / switch as well).  However, if you've set recursion to be on by default by configuring `submodule.recurse` to `true` or `1` or otherwise enabled, you can always pass an explicit `--no-recurse-submodules` option to override your override.  You can also run `git -c submodule.recurse=0`, as noted in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).